# MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable in openFileOutput

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fileoutputstream, printwriter

I am trying to save html file. I have class which extends AsyncTask

```
public class DownloadBook extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
```

Inside this class, I have this method:

```
private void writeFile(String result, String title) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(title+".html", MODE_PRIVATE);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(fos)));
        pw.print(result);
        pw.close();
    }
```

MODE_PRIVATE is giving following error:

> MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable

Then I changed it to **Context.MODE_PRIVATE**. Now openFileOutput is giving this error:

> The method openFileOutput(String, int) is undefined for the type
>   DownloadBook

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Activity or Application context to call `openFileOutput` method from  `DownloadBook` class as:

```
FileOutputStream fos = 
   getApplicationContext().openFileOutput( title+".html", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

If `DownloadBook` is separate java class then use class constructor for getting Activity context for calling `openFileOutput` method as:

```
public class DownloadBook extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private Context context;

  public DownloadBook(Context context){
   this.context=context;
  }

}
```

Now use `context` for calling `openFileOutput` method :

```
FileOutputStream fos = 
   context.openFileOutput( title+".html", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

From Activity pass context to DownloadBook class constructor :

```
DownloadBook obj_Downloadbook=new DownloadBook(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: it is giving error: The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type DownloadBook

Comment: @user3388473 : is `DownloadBook` separate java class or inner class of Activity ?